# нехватка RAM. Процесс apache2 убит OOM-killer

Tags: ubuntu, сервер

Есть виртуальный сервер c 512 Мб RAM. Ubuntu 14, Apache 2.4.7, MySQL, и другие программы для работы небольшого django сайта.. + php

Время от времени приходят сообщения такого содержания:

"нехватка RAM. Процесс apache2 и еще 2 убиты OOM-killer." или
"нехватка RAM. Процесс apache2 убит OOM-killer."

отображаются в событиях в панели управления серверами..

прилагаю статистику использования ресурсов:
[image: скриншот]

Видно, что при нормальной работе, памяти за глаза хватает. Но в какой-то момент происходит всплеск памяти и интенсивное чтение с диска. В этот момент и срабатывает OOM-killer.

Как с этим бороться? как понять, кто именно вызывает такую нагрузку?

Comment: Используете CentOS?

Comment: cheops, Ubuntu 14

Comment: swap включен? Это объяснит всплеск дисковой активности - полезли в swap, а потом и того не хватило. Примечательнее всплески LA и загрузки CPU, но без всплеска по сети. Значит не просто течёт, а что-то при этом делает. Что в dmesg? Там должно быть информации побольше. Потом, access и error-логи веб-сервера. Не помню, умеет ли апач писать ошибку, если его потомка убивает OOM, но по идее должен такое записать в лог.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день. Во-первых проблема может быть не только в Апаче. У OOM-killer'а есть система оценки важности процессов, на основе которой он и принимает решение о том, какой процесс подлежит уничтожению. У вас на одном сервере находится много различных служб, поэтому настоятельно рекомендую проверить работу так же MySQL и "других программ для работы небольшого django сайта". Хотя если вы знаете что растёт память заннятая именно Apache, то можете и не отвлекаться на это. Если же у вас нет уверенности, что память "выедает" именно Apache, то рекомендую обратить внимание на [медленные запросы](https://habrahabr.ru/post/31072/) MySQL. Тут логика проста - чем быстрее запрос выполнится, тем быстрее освободится память.

Теперь насчёт Apache. Вам нужно проверить логи сервера - возможно рост памяти связан со всплеском каких-то запросов. Если это так, дальнейшие действия будут зависить от такого, какие именно это запросы. Попробуйте так же использовать worker [event](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/event.html). А так же - установить более низкие ограничения на кол-во подключений/процессов - в таком случае при росте запросов часть клиентов не сможет подключиться к серверу, но это спасёт его от падения.

Ну и ещё один штрих - попробуйте заменить Apache на nginx. Ну или дополнить его nginx'ом, как фронтендом (т. е. сервером, принимающим на себя внешние запросы и передающий их "стоящему за ним" серверу).